# How can I include libvlc folder generated from published release build using extension Microsoft Visual Studio Installer Project?

Tags: visual-studio, vlc, libvlc

I have a project that uses VideoLAN.LibVLC.Windows nuget pkg. When I build and compile application it generates a libvlc folder.

My program builds as it should, but when I try to compile an installer using the extension Microsoft Visual Studio Installer Project it won't include the libvlc folder that is created when I build a release.

I've included the 3 options:
**Content Files,
Primary Output,
Publish Items**

The folder is generated at build so I cannot include it with Resources Properties.

How can I get the extension to include the folder for the installer?

EDIT:

My workaround is adding files manually to point to the release folder, is that correct or is there a better way?

Comment: can you share a minimal repro project please?